# Dell XPS 13 2015, Ubuntu 15.10 touchpad freezes after suspend

Tags: dell, touchpad, suspend, freeze, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 2015, qHD model running Ubuntu 15.10, kernel 4.2.0-18 and sometimes after suspend the touchpad refuses to work. Xinput no longer recognizes it, and the only way to get the touchpad to work again is to restart the laptop. The touchscreen, as well as an external mouse still work fine. I have the latest Bios installed (A05). "synclient TouchpadOff=0" doesn't seem to work, neither does "xinput set-prop 'Device Enabled' 1". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Works here flawlessly on a similar model as yours (I have no touch screen). So there must be something either hardware based or a configuration issue.

Comment: Still have the issue? Can you check and post your kernel logs - /var/log/kern.log or syslog?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my XPS12.

In case it's useful, `/var/log/kern.log` said:

```
Jun  3 13:53:49 oli-xps12 kernel: [23462.982691] i2c_hid i2c-DLL05E3:01: failed to reset device.
Jun  3 13:53:49 oli-xps12 kernel: [23462.983130] dpm_run_callback(): i2c_hid_resume+0x0/0xc0 [i2c_hid] returns -61
Jun  3 13:53:49 oli-xps12 kernel: [23462.983134] PM: Device i2c-DLL05E3:01 failed to resume: error -61
```

I could wake up the touchpad with:

```
sudo modprobe -r i2c_hid
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

I haven't tried without the first command yet as I just found the trick but it might work too...